# HTML img in PHP variable

Tags: php, html

Im trying to do this

```
$input = "<img src="HTML/images/user.png" alt="" />";
```

but it does not work out,
i know im supposed to put a / before a " or something please help

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$input = "<img src='HTML/images/user.png' alt='' />";
```

Or

```
$input = "<img src=\"HTML/images/user.png\" alt=\"\" />";
```

Comment: I'd switch the quotes for XHTML compatibility

Comment: or escape the quotes in src and alt

Comment: or

`$input = '<img src="HTML/images/user.png" alt="" />';`

`'` is fast over the `"`

Answer (score 1):

all you need to do is escape double quote.
just like below.



`\"HTML/images/user.png\" alt=\"\"`

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have use `"` for PHP already.

You can either choose to use `'` or `\"`.

For example,

```
$input = "<img src='HTML/images/user.png' alt='' />";

$input = "<img src=\"HTML/images/user.png\" alt=\"\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$input = "<img src='HTML/images/user.png' alt='' />";
```